# Change path of images uploaded on Amazon S3 using PaperClip in Rails

Tags: paperclip

How can I change the path of the images I upload using paperclip and rails. I want the path to be inside my bucket's gov_id folder and the image just stays there without any subfolders. And also how to make the url of the image to follow this format: "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/BUCKET_NAME/GOV_ID/IMAGE_NAME.EXTENSION"
Note: I have a gov_id folder inside my bucket

I have an attachment model that looks like this:

```
    class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
      has_attached_file :image, :styles => {:thumb => "200x200#"},
                        :storage => :s3,
      validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type:     ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"] }
      validates_attachment :image, presence: true

      before_save :rename_file

      def rename_file
          extension = File.extname(image_file_name).gsub(/^\.+/, '')
          new_image_file_name = "gov_#{self.attachable.reference_code}.#{extension}"

          image.instance_write(:file_name, new_image_file_name)
      end
    end
```

this stores the image uploaded to my bucket but not inside the gov_id folder. It goes to attachments/images/000/000/013/original
And the url becomes "s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/BUCKET_NAME/attachments/images/000/000/013/original/gov_UG2S463C.png?1500620951

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to assign it a new name and succeeding, but you aren't telling it to do this in a format that s3 understands.

The thing you have to remember, is that s3 buckets work based on *keys* and *objects*. If you look at an s3 bucket, the folder structure is just for show, for the most part. The file path (including the file name) is essentially the key, and the object is the image stored there (in this case).

So, the key you are assigning the image is the default paperclip path (source:
 [paperclip docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#understanding-storage)), which ends in `:file_name`

in this block

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => {:thumb => "200x200#"},
                  :storage => :s3,
```

You have a comma at the end of your has_attached_file, which I assume means you deleted things like `bucket_name:` (which is fine, but next_time, replace any sensitive info with a placeholder name. it makes the problem easier to understand).

You should have a `path:` symbol associated with the key used to access the s3 object. Usually, paperclip auto-generates this for you, but here you want to manually assign it. So you should be able to add something like this:

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => {:thumb => "200x200#"},
                          :storage => s3, 
                          :path => "/gov_id/:class/:attachment/:style/:file_name"
```

If you would like the '000/000/001' then put `:path => "/gov_id/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:file_name"`

I assume you want to have style in there so that it will deal with both the :original and :thumb style appropriately.

Also, instead of using a before_save, you might want to look into `Paperclip.interpolates`

something like:

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => {:thumb => "200x200#"},
                          :storage => s3, 
                          :path => "/gov_id/:class/:attachment/:style/:replaced_file_name"

Paperclip.interpolates :replaced_file_name do 
  extension = File.extname(image_file_name).gsub(/^\.+/, '')
  new_image_file_name = "gov_#{self.attachable.reference_code}.#{extension}"

  new_image_file_name
end
```